# EF Core one-to-many mapping to tables with no keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm trying to map tables from an old `IBM Db2` database to entities using `EntityFramework Core 2.2` but these tables don't have any keys at all (yes I was shocked too) and I'm not sure if I'm even allowed add them to this ancient beast that has been running since the stone age.

So far I've gotten things to work by reverse engineering the relationships and finding potential keys to use so that EF can happily track these entities, but I'm facing an issue with a one-to-many mapping.

I want to make a one-to-many mapping from the `Invoice` table to the `SellerAccountDetails` table. My configuration:

**Invoice entity:**

```
public class FinvoiceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Finvoice>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Finvoice> builder)
    {
        // PK for Invoice
        builder.HasKey(f => new { f.FinvoiceBatchNumber, f.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber });

        // One-to-many to SellerAccountDetails table
        builder.HasMany(f => f.SellersAccountDetails)
            .WithOne(s => s.Invoice)
            .HasForeignKey(s => new
            {
                s.FinvoiceBatchNumber,
                s.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber,
                s.SellerAccountPartyIdentifier
            })
            .HasPrincipalKey(f => new
            {
                f.FinvoiceBatchNumber,
                f.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber,
                f.SellerPartyIdentifier
            });
    }
}
```

**SellerAccountDetails entity:**

```
public class SellerAccountDetailsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SellerAccountDetails>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SellerAccountDetails> builder)
    {
        // PK for SellerAccountDetails
        builder.HasKey(s => new
        {
            s.FinvoiceBatchNumber,
            s.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber,
            s.SellerAccountPartyIdentifier,
            s.SellerAccountID // <-- Needed for uniqueness of this entity
        });

        // Many-to-one to Invoice table
        builder.HasOne(s => s.Invoice)
            .WithMany(i => i.SellersAccountDetails)
            .HasForeignKey(s => new
            {
                s.FinvoiceBatchNumber,
                s.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber,
                s.SellerAccountPartyIdentifier
            })
            .HasPrincipalKey(f => new
            {
                f.FinvoiceBatchNumber,
                f.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber,
                f.SellerPartyIdentifier
            });
    }
}
```

Now this works when I make a query and then call `ToList()`, in my test code I'm supposed to get 3 `SellerAccountDetails` entities for one `Finvoice`, but if I don't materialize the `IQueryable`, I get 6 `SellerAccountDetails` for one `Finvoice`, and if I enumerate again, they increase to 9, and so on...

Shouldn't EF know from the configured primary key on `SellerAccountDetails` what makes this entity unique?

I added the `HasPrincipalKey` because the property `SellerPartyIdentifier` (from Finvoice) corresponds to the property `SellerAccountPartyIdentifier` on the accounts table, but it's not a primary key. If I remove it and keep just the 2 foreign keys, the result is the same.

How do I make this work? I might be missing something obvious here, but I don't see it.

Here's my example query:

```
var invoices = _dbContext.Invoices.Include(i => i.SellersAccountDetails).ThenInclude(s => s.Invoice).
                Where(i => i.FinvoiceBatchNumber == 13491).OrderBy(i => i.FinvoiceBatchRowNumber).Take(1);//.ToList();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that the entity properties' getters were trimming the field:

```
private string _sellerAccountID;

[Column("FV77A", TypeName = "char(35)")]
[Required, DefaultValue("")]
[MinLength(0), MaxLength(35)]
public string SellerAccountID
{
    get { return _sellerAccountID.Trim(); } // <-- Trim() is the culprit
    set { _sellerAccountID = value; }
}
```

For some reason this was confusing the EF tracker, because if I also disable tracking by using `AsNoTracking` (or setting it globally by doing `optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);` then it would also work correctly.

I removed the trim (and the private fields), and did the trimming using `AutoMapper` on the DTO level like so:
`CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing((s, d) => s.Trim());`

Now I always get 3 results as I should no matter how many times I enumerate the IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "Include" linq without key/relationship in Db2.

You have to use below

```
var invoices = (from a in _dbContext.Invoices.Where(x => x.FinvoiceBatchNumber == 13491) 
                from b in _dbContext.SellersAccountDetails.Where(x => x.InvoiceId = a.Id).DefaultOrEmpty()
                select a, b).Take(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that wasn't it :)